# How to limit a xorg installation to a single video driver?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation

I'm trying to install xorg-server in debian wheezy.

I tried to execute a simple command

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

It attempts to install ton of video drivers and dri-modules: for nvidia, for intel, for amd, for vesa and so on. And I'd like to keep the system image as small as possible.

How to tell debian that I need the only video driver supporting the card that is present now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, [`xserver-xorg`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xserver-xorg) pulls in [`xserver-xorg-video-all`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xserver-xorg-video-all), which pulls in all the video drivers.

If you know which driver is appropriate, you can install it along with `xserver-xorg`, and it will satisfy the alternative dependency on `xorg-driver-video`, avoiding the `xserver-xorg-video-all` dependency altogether; thus for an Intel IGP:

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

If you want to make doubly sure that `xserver-xorg-video-all` isn't installed, you can use something like

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-all_
```

(note the underscore, which instructs `apt-get` to purge the package).

To avoid installing the `libdrm*` packages, you need to avoid `libgl1-mesa-dri` which depends on all of them (with no easy workaround, so if you want DRI support you need all three implementations, unless you use `equivs` — but they're quite small). `xserver-xorg` recommends the package, so

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends install xserver-xorg ...
```

should do the trick. This is a good idea anyway if you're after a small image.

Comment: Stephen, +1, what about the `_` trick? Is this just to match nothing when doing Regex match?

Comment: @heemayl it tells `apt-get` to purge the package (`+`, `-` and `_` suffixes are equivalent to `install`, `remove` and `purge` respectively, regardless of the command given to `apt-get`).